# how to get correct date diffrence

Tags: android, eclipse, date

i want to compare a date with the current date and do something if the difference is 2 months or 6 or a year .. but i have a problem how to get the correct difference for example if the current month is 02 2015 and the other month is 10 2014 i will get 8 in difference but the actual difference is 4 .. how to do it ?

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        SimpleDateFormat m = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        SimpleDateFormat ye = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        String day = d.format(c.getTime());
        String month = m.format(c.getTime());
        String year = ye.format(c.getTime());
        int d1=Integer.parseInt(day);
        int m1=Integer.parseInt(month);
        int d2=25;
        int m2=02;
        int diff=d1-d2;
        String s=String.valueOf(diff);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating your difference between two **int**, so it can't work.

You should calculate it between two **dates** or two **long** (in secondes or milliseconds)

```
long oneDay, today, delay;
oneDay = 1000*3600*24; //number of milliseconds in a day
today = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
delay = (TheDateYouWantToCompare - today)/oneDay;
if (delay >= 60*oneDay) { //more than 2 months
    //your code
}else{
    //your code
}
```

If TheDateYouWantToCompare and today are dates, it's almost the same :

```
delay = (TheDateYouWantToCompare.getTime() - today.getTime())/oneDay;
```

**Edit :**
Here it is how to get time in milliseconds.

```
String DateString = "31-12-2015"; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
Date myDate = sdf.parse(DateString); 
long timeInMilliseconds = myDate.getTime();
```

Comment: sorry but im new to this how can i convert a date to msec ? for example 12-02-2015 how it will be in msec ?

Comment: It's pretty simple :
`String DateString = "31-12-2015"; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date myDate = sdf.parse(DateString);
long timeInMilliseconds = myDate.getTime();`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the difference in milliseconds between the 2 dates. Pre-compute the differences you need/want as constants and compare to the delta you have, for example:

```
static final long DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 25;
static final long MONTH = DAY * 30;

...

int diff = d1 - d2;
if(diff > MONTH) { 
   //more than a month difference
}
```

If you need something more complex you should perhaps use a library such as [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which will give a more comprehensive set of features to work with time.